# Recording- and displaying time usage in ChessBase

Tags: chessbase, time-management

When I enter my games into ChessBase, I would like to also enter the time usage. I noticed that there is a possibility of right-clicking on the notation and choosing "move time", but this feature suffers from two problems:
1. The default time is 1:40 h and if they game was played on a different time control, this needs to be altered on each and every move.
2. There are buttons for time usage at the bottom, but the options are limited to max 9 minutes.

I'm thinking I'm maybe missing something here and there's a different way to go about things. Any recommendations of how to go about recording time usage in ChessBase?

Also - once recorded, is there a way to see a report (maybe a graph) illustrating the time usage per move?